# Make a Slideshow autoplay

Tags: javascript, joomla, slideshow

I have a Joomla module which is displaying products in a slideshow, and i want to set it playing automatically. I asked the developers of this module and said me that it isn't possible, but i can't believe them!
So i will give you now the two JS files that creating the slideshow and please if someone knows, lets help me!

File1

```
(function($) {

var SmartSlider = function(element, options){
    //Defaults are below
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.smartSlider.defaults, options);

    //Useful variables. Play carefully.
    var vars = {
        currentSlide: 0,
        currentImage: '',
        totalSlides: 0,
        running: false,
        paused: false,
        stop: true
    };

    //Get this slider
    var slider = $(element);
    slider.data('smart:vars', vars);
    slider.css('position','relative');
    slider.addClass('smartSlider');

    // var info_products = slider.find('.product_detail');

    //Max time for each slide
    var max_time_out    = Math.max(settings.boxCols * settings.boxRows*20,settings.boxCols * 2*100,settings.slices*50);

    //Find our slider children
    var kids = slider.find('.background_image').children();
    kids.each(function() {
        var child = $(this);

        //Get img width & height
        // var childWidth = child.width();
        // if(childWidth == 0) childWidth = child.attr('width');
        // if(childWidth == 0 || childWidth==undefined) childWidth = child.find("img").width();
        // var childHeight = child.height();
        // if(childHeight == 0) childHeight = child.attr('height');
        // if(childHeight == 0 || childHeight==undefined) childHeight = child.find("img").height();

        childWidth  = settings.image_width;
        childHeight = settings.image_height;

        var link = '';
        if(!child.is('img')){
            if(child.is('a')){
                child.addClass('smart-imageLink');
                link = child;
            }
            child = child.find('img:first');
        }


        //Resize the slider
        if(childWidth > slider.width()){
            slider.width(childWidth);
        }

        if(childHeight > slider.height()){
            slider.height(childHeight);
        }

        if(link != ''){
            link.css('display','none');
        }

        child.css('display','none');
        vars.totalSlides++;
    });

    if (settings.align_image=="right" && slider.width()>slider.parent().width()){
        slider.css("right",slider.width()-slider.parent().width());
    }

    var slider_width    = slider.width();
    var slider_height   = slider.height();

    // //If randomStart
    // if(settings.randomStart){
        // settings.startSlide = Math.floor(Math.random() * vars.totalSlides);
    // }

    // //Set startSlide
    // if(settings.startSlide > 0){
        // if(settings.startSlide >= vars.totalSlides) settings.startSlide = vars.totalSlides - 1;
        // vars.currentSlide = settings.startSlide;
    // }

    //Get initial image
    if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){
        vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
    } else {
        vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
    }

    //Show initial link
    if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
        $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
    }

    //Set first background
    if (settings.align_image=="left"){
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
    }else{
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
    }

    // //In the words of Super Mario "let's a go!"
    var timer = 0;
    // if(!settings.manualAdvance && kids.length > 1){
        // timer = setInterval(function(){ smartRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
    // }


    //Previous and Next button
    $('.navigation_button div.left_button', slider.parent()).bind('click', function(){
        if(vars.running) return false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = '';
        vars.currentSlide -= 2;

        // $('.info_product .product_detail', slider.parent()).remove();
        // $('.info_product', slider.parent()).append(info_products.eq(vars.currentSlide+1).css("display","block"));

        smartRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
    });

    $('.navigation_button div.right_button', slider.parent()).bind('click', function(){
        if(vars.running) return false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = '';

        // $('.info_product .product_detail', slider.parent()).remove();
        // $('.info_product', slider.parent()).append(info_products.eq(vars.currentSlide+1).css("display","block"));

        smartRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
    });


    //Change item selected
    // //Set initial active link
    // $('.navigation_sspro a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass('active');
    $('.navigation_sspro div', slider.parent()).bind('click', function(){
        if(vars.running) return false;
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = '';
        if (settings.align_image=="left"){
            // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');

            // setTimeout(function(){
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
            // }, max_time_out);
        }else{
            // setTimeout(wait_me,100);

            // // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');

            // setTimeout(function(){
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
            // }, max_time_out);
        }

        vars.currentSlide = $(this).attr("class");

        // $('.info_product .product_detail', slider.parent()).remove();
        // $('.info_product', slider.parent()).append(info_products.eq(parseInt($(this).attr("class"))+1).css("display","block"));

        smartRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
    });

    //Change item selected with style bullet
    slider.parent().find('div.bullet_button').each(function(index){
        $(this).bind("click",function(){
            if(vars.running) return false;
            if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';

            if (settings.align_image=="left"){
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');

                // setTimeout(function(){
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
                // }, max_time_out);
            }else{
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');

                // setTimeout(function(){
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
                // }, max_time_out);
            }

            vars.currentSlide = index-1;

            // $('.info_product .product_detail', slider.parent()).remove();
            // $('.info_product', slider.parent()).append(info_products.eq(index).css("display","block"));

            smartRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
        });
    });


    //Resize height of info product
    $('.info_product', slider.parent()).css("height",slider_height);

    //Change background of slider
    function change_background(){
        if (options.align_image=="left"){
            slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
        }else{
            slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
        }
    }

    //Event when Animation finishes
    slider.bind('smart:animFinished', function(){

        change_background();

        vars.running    = false; 
        slide_running   = false;
        //Hide child links
        $(kids).each(function(){
            if($(this).is('a')){
                $(this).css('display','none');
            }
        });

        //Show current link
        if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
            $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
        }

        // //Restart the timer
        // if(timer == '' && !vars.paused && !settings.manualAdvance){
            // timer = setInterval(function(){ smartRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
        // }

        //Trigger the afterChange callback
        settings.afterChange.call(this);
    });

    function start_point(){
        slide_running   = true;
    }

    // Add slices for slice animations
    var createSlices = function(slider, settings, vars){

        if (settings.align_image=="left"){
            divWrapper= $('<div/>', {
                id: 'wrapperImage'+settings.random_time
            }).css({
                position:'relative',
                top:0,
                left:0,
                height:  slider_height
            }).appendTo(slider);
        }else{
            divWrapper= $('<div/>', {
                id: 'wrapperImage'+settings.random_time
            }).css({
                position:'absolute',
                top:0,
                right: 0,
                height:  slider_height,
                // width:  vars.currentImage.attr("width")
                // width:  slider_width
                width:  vars.currentImage.width()
            }).appendTo(slider);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < settings.slices; i++){
            var sliceWidth = Math.round(slider_width/settings.slices);
            if(i == settings.slices - 1){
                divWrapper.append(
                    $('<div class="smart-slice"></div>').css({ 
                        left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', 
                        width:(slider_width-(sliceWidth*i))+'px',
                        height:'0px', 
                        opacity:'0', 
                        background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px 0%'
                    })
                );
            } else {
                divWrapper.append(
                    $('<div class="smart-slice"></div>').css({ 
                        left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', 
                        width:sliceWidth+'px',
                        height:'0px', 
                        opacity:'0', 
                        background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px 0%'
                    })
                );
            }
        }
    }

    // Add boxes for box animations
    var createBoxes = function(slider, settings, vars){
        if (settings.align_image=="left"){
            divWrapper= $('<div/>', {
                id: 'wrapperImage'+settings.random_time
            }).css({
                position:'relative',
                top:0,
                left:0
            }).appendTo(slider);
        }else{
            divWrapper= $('<div/>', {
                id: 'wrapperImage'+settings.random_time
            }).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                height:  slider_height,
                // width:  vars.currentImage.attr("width")
                //boi vi che do none nen phai de che do tren
                // width:  slider_width
                width:  vars.currentImage.width()
            }).appendTo(slider);
        }

        var boxWidth = Math.round(slider_width/settings.boxCols);
        var boxHeight = Math.round(slider_height/settings.boxRows);

        for(var rows = 0; rows < settings.boxRows; rows++){
            for(var cols = 0; cols < settings.boxCols; cols++){
                if(cols == settings.boxCols-1){
                    divWrapper.append(
                        $('<div class="smart-box"></div>').css({ 
                            opacity:0,
                            left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px', 
                            top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',
                            width:(slider_width-(boxWidth*cols))+'px',
                            height:boxHeight+'px',
                            background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((boxWidth + (cols * boxWidth)) - boxWidth) +'px -'+ ((boxHeight + (rows * boxHeight)) - boxHeight) +'px'
                        })
                    );
                } else {
                    divWrapper.append(
                        $('<div class="smart-box"></div>').css({
                            opacity:0,
                            left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px', 
                            top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',
                            width:boxWidth+'px',
                            height:boxHeight+'px',
                            background: 'url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat -'+ ((boxWidth + (cols * boxWidth)) - boxWidth) +'px -'+ ((boxHeight + (rows * boxHeight)) - boxHeight) +'px'
                        })
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Private run method
    var smartRun = function(slider, kids, settings, nudge){
        //Get our vars
        var vars = slider.data('smart:vars');

        // //Trigger the lastSlide callback
        // if(vars && (vars.currentSlide == vars.totalSlides - 1)){ 
            // settings.lastSlide.call(this);
        // }

        // Stop
        if((!vars || vars.stop) && !nudge) return false;

        //Trigger the beforeChange callback
        // settings.beforeChange.call(this);

        //Set current background before change
        if(!nudge){
            alert('co bao jo em biet');
            if (settings.align_image=="left"){
                slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
            }else{
                slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
            }
            // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
        } else {
            if(nudge == 'prev'){
                if (settings.align_image=="left"){
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');

                    // setTimeout(function(){
                        // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
                    // }, max_time_out);
                }else{
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');

                    // setTimeout(function(){
                        // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
                    // }, max_time_out);
                }
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
            }
            if(nudge == 'next'){
                if (settings.align_image=="left"){
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');

                    // setTimeout(function(){
                        // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
                    // }, max_time_out);
                }else{
                    // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');

                    // setTimeout(function(){
                        // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat right top');
                    // }, max_time_out);
                }
                // slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
            }
        }
        vars.currentSlide++;

       //Trigger the slideshowEnd callback
        if(vars.currentSlide == vars.totalSlides){ 
            vars.currentSlide = 0;
            // settings.slideshowEnd.call(this);
        }

        if(vars.currentSlide < 0) vars.currentSlide = (vars.totalSlides - 1);
        //Set vars.currentImage
        if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
        } else {
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
        }

        // //Set active links
        // if(settings.controlNav){
            // $('.smart-controlNav a', slider).removeClass('active');
            // $('.smart-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass('active');
        // }

        //Set active links
        // if(settings.controlNav){
            $('.navigation_sspro div', slider.parent()).removeClass('active');
            $('.navigation_sspro div:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider.parent()).addClass('active');
        // }

        // //Process caption
        // processCaption(settings);

        // Remove any slices from last transition
        // $('.smart-slice', slider).remove();

        // Remove any boxes from last transition
        // $('.smart-box', slider).remove();
        $('#wrapperImage'+settings.random_time, slider).remove();

        var currentEffect = settings.effect;
        //Generate random effect
        if(settings.effect == 'random'){
            var anims = new Array('sliceDownRight','sliceDownLeft','sliceUpRight','sliceUpLeft','sliceUpDown','sliceUpDownLeft','fold','fade',
            'boxRandom','boxRain','boxRainReverse','boxRainGrow','boxRainGrowReverse');
            currentEffect = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length + 1))];
            if(currentEffect == undefined) currentEffect = 'fade';
        }

        //Run random effect from specified set (eg: effect:'fold,fade')
        if(settings.effect.indexOf(',') != -1){
            var anims = settings.effect.split(',');
            currentEffect = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length))];
            if(currentEffect == undefined) currentEffect = 'fade';
        }

       /*  //Custom transition as defined by "data-transition" attribute
        if(vars.currentImage.attr('data-transition')){
            currentEffect = vars.currentImage.attr('data-transition');
        } */

        //Run effects
        vars.running    = true;

        setTimeout(start_point,10);

        if(currentEffect == 'sliceDown' || currentEffect == 'sliceDownRight' || currentEffect == 'sliceDownLeft'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
            var timeBuff = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var slices = $('.smart-slice', slider);
            if(currentEffect == 'sliceDownLeft') slices = $('.smart-slice', slider)._reverse();

            slices.each(function(){
                var slice = $(this);
                slice.css({ 'top': '0px' });
                if(i == settings.slices-1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                }
                timeBuff += 50;
                i++;
            });
        } 
        else if(currentEffect == 'sliceUp' || currentEffect == 'sliceUpRight' || currentEffect == 'sliceUpLeft'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
            var timeBuff = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var slices = $('.smart-slice', slider);
            if(currentEffect == 'sliceUpLeft') slices = $('.smart-slice', slider)._reverse();

            slices.each(function(){
                var slice = $(this);
                slice.css({ 'bottom': '0px' });
                if(i == settings.slices-1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                }
                timeBuff += 50;
                i++;
            });
        } 
        else if(currentEffect == 'sliceUpDown' || currentEffect == 'sliceUpDownRight' || currentEffect == 'sliceUpDownLeft'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
            var timeBuff = 0;
            var i = 0;
            var v = 0;
            var slices = $('.smart-slice', slider);
            if(currentEffect == 'sliceUpDownLeft') slices = $('.smart-slice', slider)._reverse();

            slices.each(function(){
                var slice = $(this);
                if(i == 0){
                    slice.css('top','0px');
                    i++;
                } else {
                    slice.css('bottom','0px');
                    i = 0;
                }

                if(v == settings.slices-1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                }
                timeBuff += 50;
                v++;
            });
        } 
        else if(currentEffect == 'fold'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
            var timeBuff = 0;
            var i = 0;

            $('.smart-slice', slider).each(function(){
                var slice = $(this);
                var origWidth = slice.width();
                slice.css({ top:'0px', height:'100%', width:'0px' });
                if(i == settings.slices-1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ width:origWidth, opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        slice.animate({ width:origWidth, opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                }
                timeBuff += 50;
                i++;
            });
        }  
        else if(currentEffect == 'fade'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);

            var firstSlice = $('.smart-slice:first', slider);
            firstSlice.css({
                'height': '100%',
                'width': slider_width + 'px'
            });

            firstSlice.animate({ opacity:'1.0' }, (settings.animSpeed*2), '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
        }          
        else if(currentEffect == 'slideInRight'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);

            var firstSlice = $('.smart-slice:first', slider);
            firstSlice.css({
                'height': '100%',
                'width': '0px',
                'opacity': '1'
            });

            firstSlice.animate({ width: slider_width + 'px' }, (settings.animSpeed*2), '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
        }
        else if(currentEffect == 'slideInLeft'){
            createSlices(slider, settings, vars);

            var firstSlice = $('.smart-slice:first', slider);
            firstSlice.css({
                'height': '100%',
                'width': '0px',
                'opacity': '1',
                'left': '',
                'right': '0px'
            });

            firstSlice.animate({ width: slider_width + 'px' }, (settings.animSpeed*2), '', function(){ 
                // Reset positioning
                firstSlice.css({
                    'left': '0px',
                    'right': ''
                });
                slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); 
            });
        }
        else if(currentEffect == 'boxRandom'){
            createBoxes(slider, settings, vars);

            var totalBoxes = settings.boxCols * settings.boxRows;
            var i = 0;
            var timeBuff = 0;

            var boxes = shuffle($('.smart-box', slider));
            boxes.each(function(){
                var box = $(this);
                if(i == totalBoxes-1){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        box.animate({ opacity:'1' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        box.animate({ opacity:'1' }, settings.animSpeed);
                    }, (100 + timeBuff));
                }
                timeBuff += 20;
                i++;
            });
        }
        else if(currentEffect == 'boxRain' || currentEffect == 'boxRainReverse' || currentEffect == 'boxRainGrow' || currentEffect == 'boxRainGrowReverse'){

            createBoxes(slider, settings, vars);

            var totalBoxes = settings.boxCols * settings.boxRows;
            var i = 0;
            var timeBuff = 0;

            // Split boxes into 2D array
            var rowIndex = 0;
            var colIndex = 0;
            var box2Darr = new Array();
            box2Darr[rowIndex] = new Array();
            var boxes = $('.smart-box', slider);
            if(currentEffect == 'boxRainReverse' || currentEffect == 'boxRainGrowReverse'){
                boxes = $('.smart-box', slider)._reverse();
            }
            boxes.each(function(){
                box2Darr[rowIndex][colIndex] = $(this);
                colIndex++;
                if(colIndex == settings.boxCols){
                    rowIndex++;
                    colIndex = 0;
                    box2Darr[rowIndex] = new Array();
                }
            });

            // Run animation
            for(var cols = 0; cols < (settings.boxCols * 2); cols++){
                var prevCol = cols;
                for(var rows = 0; rows < settings.boxRows; rows++){
                    if(prevCol >= 0 && prevCol < settings.boxCols){
                        /* Due to some weird JS bug with loop vars 
                        being used in setTimeout, this is wrapped
                        with an anonymous function call */
                        (function(row, col, time, i, totalBoxes) {
                            var box = $(box2Darr[row][col]);
                            var w = box.width();
                            var h = box.height();
                            if(currentEffect == 'boxRainGrow' || currentEffect == 'boxRainGrowReverse'){
                                box.width(0).height(0);
                            }
                            if(i == totalBoxes-1){
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    box.animate({ opacity:'1', width:w, height:h }, settings.animSpeed/1.3, '', function(){ slider.trigger('smart:animFinished'); });
                                }, (100 + time));
                            } else {
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    box.animate({ opacity:'1', width:w, height:h }, settings.animSpeed/1.3);
                                }, (100 + time));
                            }
                        })(rows, prevCol, timeBuff, i, totalBoxes);
                        i++;
                    }
                    prevCol--;
                }
                timeBuff += 100;
            }
        }
        // alert(timeBuff);
    }

    // Shuffle an array
    var shuffle = function(arr){
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    }

    // For debugging
    var trace = function(msg){
        if (this.console && typeof console.log != "undefined")
            console.log(msg);
    }

    // Start / Stop
    this.stop = function(){
        if(!$(element).data('smart:vars').stop){
            $(element).data('smart:vars').stop = true;
            trace('Stop Slider');
        }
    }

    this.start = function(){
        if($(element).data('smart:vars').stop){
            $(element).data('smart:vars').stop = false;
            trace('Start Slider');
        }
    }

    // //Trigger the afterLoad callback
    // settings.afterLoad.call(this);

    return this;
};

$.fn.smartSlider = function(options) {

    return this.each(function(key, value){
        var element = $(this);
        // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
        if (element.data('smartslider')) return element.data('smartslider');
        // Pass options to plugin constructor
        var smartslider = new SmartSlider(this, options);
        // Store plugin object in this element's data
        element.data('smartslider', smartslider);
    });

};

//Default settings
$.fn.smartSlider.defaults = {
    effect                      : 'random', //'boxRain',
    slices                      : 15,
    boxCols                     : 8,
    boxRows                     : 4,
    animSpeed                   : 500,
    pauseTime                   : 3000,
    random_time                 : "",
    align_image                 : "left",
    image_width                 : 765,
    image_height                : 500,
    afterChange                 : function(){}
};

$.fn._reverse = [].reverse;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So you want to to read thousands of lines, to figure out how it works and make it work for you?

Comment: could you provide a link to the module if it's a free one so it can be tested. you're more likely to get an exact answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

What if you change line 12:

```
    running: true,
```

and line 14:

```
    stop: false
```

Does it work? mine is a suggestion, i don't know this slider, it is the first thing that i thought, hope it helps